# jQuery loading intermittently when uploaded to host

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no;">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="style/master.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width:420px)" href="style/master420.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="images/bottom-01.svg" id="logobottom">
        <img src="images/top-01.svg" id="logotop" class="logotop">
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function(){
            $("#logo").fadeIn(500);
            var logoTop = ($(window).outerHeight() - $("#logotop").height())/2;
            $("#logo").css("margin-top",logoTop);
            $(window).resize(function(){
                $("#logo").css("height","auto");
                var logoTop = ($(window).outerHeight() - $("#logotop").height())/2;
                $("#logo").css("margin-top",logoTop);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This website and this script work perfectly when I open it on my browser off my hard drive but when I upload it to the host (GoDaddy), it works intermittently. Why would a website work off a hard drive but not work after it's been uploaded to the host?

Comment: What works intermittently, the entire script or just the resize part?

Comment: btw you don't need to use `jQuery(handler);` because you have inserted your jQuery at the very bottom of your `<body>`. So the script already loads when the structure has been loaded successfully.

Comment: What does the javascript console say?  What are the values of logoTop at the various points that it is instantiated?  My guess is that the images are still loading in and the height that is calculated is wrong as a result.  Try encapsulating your code in a `$(window).on('load', function(){ ... })` to force it to wait for the images to fully load.

Comment: @Zealander I've actually noticed that the script only loads after the window is resized (when hosted). Off my hard drive the page loads fine on every browser.

Comment: That's because loading the images from hard drive is almost instant.  The fact that it works for the resize function makes me believe it just hasn't fully loaded the images yet when you first try to set the `margin-top`

Comment: @JosephMarikle that worked, very nicely done. Make that an answer so I can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the images are still loading in and the height that is calculated is wrong as a result. Try encapsulating your code in a $(window).on('load', function(){ ... }) to force it to wait for the images to fully load.

This would look something like this:

```
    window.on('load', function(){
        $("#logo").fadeIn(500);
        var logoTop = ($(window).outerHeight() - $("#logotop").height())/2;
        $("#logo").css("margin-top",logoTop);
        $(window).resize(function(){
            $("#logo").css("height","auto");
            var logoTop = ($(window).outerHeight() - $("#logotop").height())/2;
            $("#logo").css("margin-top",logoTop);
        });
    });
```

Not really part of the answer but you can also optimize the size of your script by using `.trigger('resize')` like so:

```
    window.on('load', function(){
        $("#logo").fadeIn(500);
        $(window).resize(function(){
            $("#logo").css("height","auto");
            var logoTop = ($(window).outerHeight() - $("#logotop").height())/2;
            $("#logo").css("margin-top",logoTop);
        }).trigger('resize');
    });
```